# Узнать URL категории

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте! Хочу узнать ID категории поста. Зная id поста как это можно сделать? P.S. Категория кастомная, таксономия `ad_cat`.

Comment: Немного перефразировал вопрос

Comment: У вас заголовок не соответствует тексту. URL или ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код такой:

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'ad_cat' );
$ad_cat_id = $terms[0]->term_id;
```

Вообще-то, $terms - это массив терминов таксономии ad_cat для данного поста. Но обычно у поста один термин таксономии, так что извлекаем первый элемент массива.